# Android - ListView row background color change

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I created a ListView with two background color row by row.Then I need to change its background color when click on item and back to its own color loss focusing the item.
I tried with below code and view.setBackgroundResource() does not working properly in side the ItemClickListener.

```
 if (selectedView != null) {
    if (selectedRowIndex % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_secondcolor);
    } else {
     view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_firstcolor);
    }
    }selectedRowIndex = position;
    selectedView = view;view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Is there any other possible way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the view first invoke `setBackgroundResource`, and then invoke `setBackgroundColor` maybe it's reason, try remove one.

Comment: Do you get any of the listitems color set? Or you are getting all with white colored background?

Comment: No.Issue is after loss focus the item it does not go to its previous color.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily via XML. You have to define a drawable with different states. In your case, as the background color of the list items should alternate, you have to define two drawables.

In this drawable you define the color for the different states the list item can have. Normal, focused, pressed, focused and pressed. Then you simply apply this drawable to the background attribute of the list item.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
            <!-- default -->
            <item android:drawable="@color/normal_color" />
            <!-- focused -->
            <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/focused_color" /> 
            <!-- pressed --> 
            <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" />  
            <!-- focused and pressed-->
            <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/focused_pressed_color" />
        </selector>
```